# Deploying a silverlight webapp from Visual Studio 2010 to Windows 7 IIS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, iis-7

Hope somebody can give me some info regarding this.

I have a silverlight web app (.NET 4). I would like to use msdeploy to deploy it to IIS 7 running on a Windows 7 64 bit machine.

I have read many pages and have tried a lot of the steps in them so far but am still struggling.

What I have done:

```
1. Installed Web Platform Installer.
2. Installed msdeploy
3. Started and set to automatically start: "Web Deployment Agent Service" and "Web Management Service"
4. Created a web site in IIS 7 and set permissions.
5. Tested the website "http://server/page and get a blank directory browsing because nothing is added yet.
```

So now I would like to deploy but am getting an error : "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it:10.224.201.117:8172

I have tested telnet'ing to the address on port 8172 which fails.

It is suggested that msdeploy is not configured correctly and I need to Enable Remote Connections. However it does not seem that Windows 7 IIS 7 has the icons in IIS to do this. (No "Management Service" option under add / remove features of IIS)
Does this mean i can not deploy to Windows 7 IIS 7?
Or is there another way to enable remote connections, perhaps using powershell?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Tx

Neill